# CMTimeGetSeconds duration and addPeriodicTimeObserver doesn't equal at the end

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Does anyone know why my CMTimeGetSeconds value from duration, and addPeriodicTimeObserver are not equal? It works great if total seconds are less than 0.5 hour but not if over it. Thanks!

```
audioPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in
  currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)

  if let duration = self.audioPlayer?.currentItem?.duration {
     let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

     if currentSeconds == durationSeconds {
        self.handleAudioFinishPlaying()
     }
  }
})
```

I print them out and this is the result: 5303.088 for durationSeconds and  5303.112 for duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the times are coming from different sources, there might be slightly discrepancies on the 'delta' of milliseconds, hence you should `round` them doing so:

```
 if floor(currentSeconds) == floor(durationSeconds) {
    self.handleAudioFinishPlaying()
 }
```

Comment: Yeah. I think so too. I rounded using Int but floor worked as well. Thanks!